# In PHP: what is the difference between "return", "yield", "yield from" and mixing both yield and return in same function?

Tags: php, return, generator, yield

The difference between `return` and `yield` seemed clear until I figured out there was also `yield from` and the possibility to combine both `return` and `yield` in the very same function!

My understanding of `return` was that everything after was **not** executed, right?

However:

```
function generate(): iterable {
    return [1, 2, 3];
}

foreach (generate() as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Produces: "123"

But the following:

```
function generate(): iterable {
    return [1, 2, 3];
    yield;
}

foreach (generate() as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Produces nothing! So that means yield is executed?

Is this a bug?

Comment: `var_dump(generate()->GetReturn());`

Answer (score 21):

## `Return`

Simply gives back a unique value to the caller.

## `Yield`

Transform the current function/method to return a [`Generator`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.php), which will produce more than a unique value: every times `yield` is triggered, it gives the value to the caller, one at a time, traditionally using a `foreach` loop.

## `Yield` + `Return`

Generators, in addition to generate values, can also, provide a unique returned value. That value won't be part of the looping around the generator, it must be accessed using [`Generator::getReturn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.getreturn.php) method.

## `Return` + `Yield`

This could be seen as a bug, however, it is not.

They are two phases:

1. **From code to bytecode**: during this phase, the `generate()` function is seen to contain the `yield` keyword, it is therefore marked as producing a `Generator`.
2. **Execution**: Because the `return` happens to be before the `yield`, the generator doesn't have the chance to produce any value. However, the `[1, 2, 3]` array can be retrieved with [`Generator::getReturn()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.getreturn.php).

## A complete annotated example:

```
// Generate integers 1 and 2
function generateIntegers1And2(): Generator {
    yield 1;                                  // <--+   <--+   <--+
    yield 2;                                  //  <-+    <-+    <-+
}                                             //    |      |      |
                                              //    |      |      |
foreach (generateIntegers1And2() as $value) { //    |      |      |
    var_dump($value); // Shows 1, then 2          ->*      |      |
}                                                       // |      |
                                                        // |      |
function generateOuterYield(): Generator {              // |      |
    // Yields the generator *itself* returned by           |      |
    // generateIntegers1And2() not the actual values       |      |
    // generated by it.                                    |      |
    // This means we are producing here a generator        |      |
    // of generator of integers.                           |      |
    yield generateIntegers1And2();          // <-+         |      |
}                                             // |         |      |
                                              // |         |      |
foreach (generateOuterYield() as $value) {    // |         |      |
    var_dump($value);                       // ->*         |      |
    // The two levels of imbrication means we have         |      |
    // to loop once more to actually consume               |      |
    // generateIntegers1And2                               |      |
    foreach ($value as $val) {                          // |      |
        var_dump($val); // Shows 1, then 2               ->*      |
    }                                                          // |
}                                                              // |
                                                               // |
// A generator can just be returned as-is:                        |
function generateOuterReturn(): Generator {                    // |
    return generateIntegers1And2();                            // |
}                                                              // |
                                                               // |
// it doesn't change the way it is consumed                       |
foreach (generateOuterReturn() as $value) {                    // |
    var_dump($value); // Shows 1, then 2                          |
}                                                              // |
                                                               // |
function generateOuterYieldFrom(): Generator {                 // |
    // First yield values generated by generateIntegers1And2()    |
    yield from generateIntegers1And2();                        // *<---+
    // then yield integers 3                                           |
    yield 3;                                                     // <--+
    // and 4                                                           |
    yield 4;                                                     //  <-+
}                                                                //    |
                                                                 //    |
foreach (generateOuterYieldFrom() as $value) {                   //    |
    var_dump($value); // Shows 1, 2, 3 and 4                         ->*
}

function generateIntegers56AndReturn(): Generator {
    yield 5;                                                  // <---+
    yield 6;                                                  //  <--+
                                                              //     |
    return ["five", "six"];                       // <--+            |
}                                                 //    |            |
                                                  //    |            |
$gen = generateIntegers56AndReturn();             //    |            |
                                                  //    |            |
// Consume the values **yielded** by                    |            |
// generateIntegers56AndReturn()                        |            |
foreach ($gen as $value) {                        //    |            |
    var_dump($value); // Shows 5, then 6                |          ->*
}                                                 //    |
                                                  //    |
// Access the value **returned** by the generator       |
var_dump($gen->getReturn());                      //  ->*

function wtf(): Generator {
    return ["W", "T", "F", "!"];
    // Without the following line, PHP would complain with a TypeError:
    // Return value of wtf() must be an instance of Generator, array returned.
    // The presence of a yield keyword anywhere inside the function makes it a Generator.
    // However, since we return *before* reaching any *yield*, 42 is never yielded.
    // This is empty generator!
    yield 42;
}

$gen = wtf();

// This foreach loop is not entered!
foreach ($gen as $value) {
    var_dump($value);
}

// However, we can loop on the array *returned* by wtf():
foreach ($gen->getReturn() as $value) {
    echo $value; // Will print: WTF!
}
```

Comment: The last example, the return "ends" the function execution, that is, the code doesnt achieve the yeld.

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php):

> Any function containing `yield` is a generator function.

So it doesn't matter whether the `yield` is executed, the parser sees it somewhere in the function definition and turns it into a generator.

If the function never executes the `yield` statement, then the generator doesn't produce any values. The value returned by `return` is ignored when you try to use the result. The documentation says:

> **Note:**
>   
>   In PHP 5, a generator could not return a value: doing so would result in a compile error. An empty `return` statement was valid syntax within a generator and it would terminate the generator. Since PHP 7.0, a generator can return values, which can be retrieved using [Generator::getReturn()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/generator.getreturn.php).

So you could do:

```
$gen = generate();
foreach ($gen as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
print_r($gen->getReturn());
```